# Using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE), is there a way to check if a post is flagged duplicate?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I want to check that question number 34947866 is flagged as duplicate by querying using the data explorer. How can I do this? I found the duplicate flag in the CloseReasonTypes table, but where is this Type applied to a post?

Comment: Related: *[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the `PostHistory` table for a "Post Closed" record. For example, see [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/510722).

You can't see data about whether it was *flagged* as a duplicate from SEDE.

Answer (score 2):

To see all the questions that have currently (well, when it was updated) pending duplicate flags, you can use this query:

```
select postid as [Post Link], 
       duplicateofquestionid as [Post Link] 
from pendingflags 
where duplicateofquestionid is not null
```

Comment: Id 34947866 is not returned by this query.

Comment: @greenberet123 unfortunately, SEDE is only updated once a week, every Sunday morning.

Comment: @greenberet123 It's already [closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947866), there are no pending flags.

Comment: @Laurel - Yup, exactly.